# "ng new xxx" giving error errorcode -4048

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

When I run 'ng new projectName' in vs code, I get the following failure.

```
ng new VirtualScroll

? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? SCSS   [ http://sass-lang.com   ]
CREATE VirtualScroll/angular.json (3922 bytes)
 .
 .
 .
CREATE VirtualScroll/e2e/src/app.po.ts (204 bytes)
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @angular/compiler@~7.1.0 (sha512-AvYXtjEJ27Rhv4c27DXNEa58Lit63jdydzbz7VuyFhNU+FwDUK2DC4gZe0nWZsf7HUniJezVRFkECDCZQeSKCQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ykhatri\Documents\Angular\VirtualScroll\node_modules\.staging\less-8679cb3c\test\less\no-strict-math\mixins-guards.less'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ykhatri\Documents\Angular\VirtualScroll\node_modules\.staging\less-8679cb3c\test\less\no-strict-math\no-sm-operations.less'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ykhatri\Documents\Angular\VirtualScroll\node_modules\.staging\less-8679cb3c\test\less\postProcessorPlugin\postProcessor.less'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ykhatri\Documents\Angular\VirtualScroll\node_modules\.staging\less-8679cb3c\test\less\strict-units\strict-units.less'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ykhatri\Documents\Angular\VirtualScroll\node_modules\.staging\@angular\common-7dabc48e\testing\src\location_mock.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ykhatri\Documents\Angular\VirtualScroll\node_modules\.staging\@angular\common-7dabc48e\testing\src\mock_location_strategy.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ykhatri\Documents\Angular\VirtualScroll\node_modules\.staging\@angular\common-7dabc48e\testing\src\testing.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ykhatri\Documents\Angular\VirtualScroll\node_modules\.staging\@angular\common-7dabc48e\testing\testing.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ykhatri\Documents\Angular\VirtualScroll\node_modules\.staging\@angular\common-7dabc48e\testing\testing.metadata.json'
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ykhatri\Documents\Angular\VirtualScroll\node_modules\.staging\@angular\compiler-8dda22ba\fesm2015\compiler.js
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\ykhatri\Documents\Angular\VirtualScroll\node_modules\.staging\@angular\compiler-8dda22ba\fesm2015\compiler.js'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\ykhatri\Documents\Angular\VirtualScroll\node_modules\.staging\@angular\compiler-8dda22ba\fesm2015\compiler.js']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\ykhatri\Documents\Angular\VirtualScroll\node_modules\.staging\@angular\compiler-8dda22ba\fesm2015\compiler.js'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!      path:
npm ERR!       'C:\\Users\\ykhatri\\Documents\\Angular\\VirtualScroll\\node_modules\\.staging\\@angular\\compiler-8dda22ba\\fesm2015\\compiler.js' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\\Users\\ykhatri\\Documents\\Angular\\VirtualScroll\\node_modules\\.staging\\@angular\\compiler-8dda22ba\\fesm2015\\compiler.js'",
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    'C:\\Users\\ykhatri\\Documents\\Angular\\VirtualScroll\\node_modules\\.staging\\@angular\\compiler-8dda22ba\\fesm2015\\compiler.js',
npm ERR!   parent: 'virtual-scroll' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ykhatri\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-16T14_58_04_245Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

i have tried following solutions but the error is same

1. npm clean cache --force
2. reinstalled node.js
3. closed all other applications which might access node
4. reinstalled angular cli globally using `npm install -g @angular/cli`

angular cli version :-

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.1
Node: 11.6.0
OS: win32 x64
```

after all these warning and error node_modules folder of the project only contain empty folders

```
 .....\VirtualScroll\node_modules\.staging\@angular\compiler-8dda22ba\esm2015\src\render3
```

Comment: Reinstall Angular cli `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: @cgTag already reinstalled

Comment: I found this related issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12726

Comment: The issue comments say to install TypeScript globally, but I do not recommend this. If you have it installed globally, then maybe try uninstalling it. If you need it globally try reinstalling with the version needed by 7.1.1 (I don't know what it is, sorry)

Comment: I am using TypeScript 3.1.6 with Angular 7.1.3

Comment: @cgtag let me check it

Comment: thanks buddy @cgTag

Comment: it worked i installed typescript 3.1.6 globally it is showing some warnings but project is created now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
npm install typescript@YOUR-COMPATIBLE-VERSION
```

in my case it worked with typescript@3.1.6

suggested by [@cgtag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1031569/cgtag) in comment section of the same post